# How to prevent a revealed row from breaking a tables formatting?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table with [many] hidden rows and a little bit of jQuery/css to hide/reveal the rows based on a click.
I works for the most part, click a row and the hidden one gets revealed, click again, it gets hidden.

The problem is that when a row is clicked on, the row that gets revealed pushes all the content of the previous[clickable] row to the right as if the second row was taking up only the first cell [which it isn't - see below].

If I remove the classes to hide the hidden rows, the whole table displays just fine, no format issues at all;

What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Here is the html:

```
<tr class="clickable" id="67">
    <td align="left">Visible row</td>
    <td align="right">$150,000.00</td>
    <td align="right">$150,000.00</td>
    <td align="right">$9,000.00</td>
    <td align="right">$0.00</td>
</tr>

<tr class="collapse out contracts" id="67collapsed">
    <td align="left">Hidden row</td>
    <td align="right">$150,000.00</td>
    <td align="right">$150,000.00</td>
    <td align="right">$9,000.00</td>
    <td align="right">$0.00</td>
</tr>
```

and the script:

```
<script>
$(".clickable").click(function() {

var id = $(this).attr('id');
var target = '#'+id+'collapsed';

if($(target).hasClass("out")) {
        $(target).addClass("in");
        $(target).removeClass("out");
    } else {
        $(target).addClass("out");
        $(target).removeClass("in");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using the twitter bootstrap framework by any chance?

Comment: What is your browser? It seems to be working fine on chrome http://jsfiddle.net/8bWtG/

Comment: It is bootstrap, I found the issue, bootstrap displays the collapse.in as block, I needed to add: tr.collapse.in.contracts {display:table-row;}

Comment: Breaks when bootstrap is included: http://jsfiddle.net/8bWtG/1/